# Somar resultado de outra soma

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando realizar uma soma do resultado de outra operação. Segue abaixo o código que estou tentando

```
    select
    distinct

    (SELECT(SUM(CAST(ROUND(ppre.Valor_Custo, 2) as decimal(18,2))) )) * 

    (select  isnull(sum(case when e.Quantidade < 0 then 0 else e.Quantidade 
    end),0)from Estoque e 
    inner join deposito d on d.ID = e.ID_Deposito and d.ID_Empresa in (1,2) 
    and 
    d.Ativo = 1 
    where  e.ID_Produto = prod.ID)


    as 'Custo total'
    FROM Produto prod 
    inner join Produto_Empresa ppre on ppre.ID_Produto = prod.ID

    group by prod.id
```

Esse é o resultado da consulta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para transformar esses dois resultados em um só?

Obs: já tentei acrescentar um `SUM` mas não deu certo.

Comment: Tira o `group by`

Comment: como o @Sorack falou, está agrupando, se tirar o group vai trazer uma soma só, ou usa uma CTE:  `with dados as ( ...aqui vai seu select ...) select sum('Custo total') from dados`

Answer (score 0):

Como falado nos comentários, você deve remover o `group by`; os resultados apresentados serão trazidos em apenas uma linha, já que não existe divisão/agrupamento por `id`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (SELECT(SUM(CAST(ROUND(ppre.Valor_Custo, 2) as decimal(18,2))) )) * 
    (select  isnull(sum(case when e.Quantidade < 0 then 0 else e.Quantidade end),0)
     FROM Estoque e 
     INNER JOIN deposito d ON d.ID = e.ID_Deposito AND d.ID_Empresa in (1,2) AND d.Ativo = 1 
     WHERE e.ID_Produto = prod.ID) AS 'Custo total'
FROM Produto prod 
INNER JOIN Produto_Empresa ppre on ppre.ID_Produto = prod.ID
```